# Checking if a line starts with contents in a list

Tags: java

I have a list that looks like this:

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("//", "/*", "*", "}", "{");
```

I then read in a file and go through it line by line.  I'd like to check to see if the beginning of the line matches any of what's in the list.

I was doing it this way earlier, but this doesn't seem like it's the most efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to do:

```
/*
if (!strLine.startsWith("//") && !strLine.startsWith("/*") && !strLine.startsWith("*")  && !strLine.startsWith("}") && !strLine.startsWith("{")) {
System.out.println(strLine);
}
*/
```

Any suggestions on what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on regular expressions.

Comment: I was thinking that would be the easiest way as well, but other people said to shy away from it.  Maybe I"ll give this another shot and see what happens

Comment: @joshft91: regex are a powerful tool, they are occasionally overused and can turn ugly when used too excessively. For things like this they are pretty much exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isInList(List<String> list, String strline){
   for(String message:list){
     if(strline.startsWith(message)){
       return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}

//Usage
String someString = "something";
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("//", "/*", "*", "}", "{");

if(isInList(messages,someString)){
   System.out.println("foundMatch");
}
```

Comment: This is what I was working with at first, but I need to only check the first couple characters of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression and a matcher for this. But you can't use a List of strings, but you can build it at runtime.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(//|/\\*|\\*|\\{|\\}).*").matcher("");
if (!matcher.reset(strLine).matches()) {
   // does not start
}
```

Sample :

```
String str = "abc\n// foo\n/* foo */\nthing\n{bar\n{baz\nlol";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(//|/\\*|\\*|\\{|\\}).*").matcher("");
for (String strLine : str.split("\n")) {
    if (!matcher.reset(strLine).matches()) {
        System.out.println(strLine + " does not match");
    }
}
```

prints:

```
abc does not match
thing does not match
lol does not match
```

You could build the Pattern dynamically by using `Pattern.quote`:

```
public static Pattern patternOf(List<String> starts) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (String start: starts) {
        b.append("|").append(Pattern.quote(start));
    }
    return Pattern.compile("^(" + b.substring(1) + ").*");
}
// use it like this:
Matcher matcher = patternOf(Arrays.asList("//", "/*", "*", "{", "}")).matcher("");
// produces a pattern like: ^(\Q//\E|\Q/*\E|\Q*\E|\Q{\E|\Q}\E).*
```

Comment: This regex does not correspond to what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @assylias: Tested the regex online before writing the code here.

Answer (score 0):

For the small number of tests you're doing, that's not unreasonable. You're eliminating the overhead of a loop or iterator, and you're eliminating the parsing and execution of a regular expression as was suggested by a comment.

Consider ordering the tests so the most common of the four strings is listed first. That way the test will pass as quickly as possible.

I don't think in the grand scheme of things this is a big deal. Accessing the file is going to be the slowest part of what you're doing. A handful of string compares is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with Apache Commons Lang: [`StringUtils.startsWithAny`](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#startsWithAny%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence...%29).

For example:

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("//", "/*", "*", "}", "{");
boolean startsWith = StringUtils.startsWithAny("{mystring}", messages.toArray(new String[messages.size()]));
```